# Is there any way to assign Array String to method java.lang.String.endwith(String suffix)

Tags: java, arrays, string, file

I need to a file's suffix with an array list like

```
String[] FileType = {"pdf","mp3","jpg"}
File SourceFileToCheckType = new File("C:\\Users\\RS\\Desktop\\test.pdf");
```

using method below.... this method is full off errors how to deal with such situation

```
public static boolean FileTypeAccept(File SourceFileToCheckType, String[] fileType) 
    {

            for (String filetypeS : fileType)

            return SourceFileToCheckType.getName().endsWith("." + filetypeS);


    }
```

Comment: Well one error I can see is: - `your method is missng a return statement`. Is it that? As you haven't posted it.

Comment: i knew... following ans solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done. Try this code:

```
public static boolean FileTypeAccept(File source, String[] fileTypes) 
{
    for (String filetype : fileTypes)
        if (source.getAbsolutePath().endsWith("." + filetype))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regex:

```
SourceFileToCheckType.getName().matches(".*(pdf|mp3|jpg)$")
```

If you wanted to make it a variable:

```
String fileTypes = "pdf|mp3|jpg";

SourceFileToCheckType.getName().matches(".*(" + fileTypes + ")$")
```

Also, in java prefer naming variables starting with a lower case letter.